# Write a test for a asynchronous function throwing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

This works:

```
const err = new exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError('');
const fn = function () { throw err; };
expect(fn).to.throw(err);
```

How would one write a test for an async function though?

```
const err = new exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError('');
const fn = async function () { throw err; };
expect(fn).to.throw(err);
```

The above doesn't work.

Comment: whats npm are you using for testing?

Answer (score 1):

Functions defined with [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) return a `Promise` when called. There's a plugin for Chai called [Chai as Promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) that you can use to test your function.

Install Chai as Promised from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised):

```
$ npm install chai-as-promised --save-dev
```

Plug it into Chai:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;
```

Then write a test for your async function. If your test environment allows you to return a `Promise` from a test (like Mocha), then do this:

```
const err = new exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError('');
const fn = async function () { throw err; };
return expect(fn()).to.be.rejectedWith(err);
```

If your test environment doesn't let you return a `Promise`, do this instead:

```
const err = new exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError('');
const fn = async function () { throw err; };
expect(fn()).to.be.rejectedWith(err).notify(done); // where `done` is the callback
```

Note that the function's return value (a `Promise`) is passed to `expect()`, rather than the function itself.